# compare text with linebreaks in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I tried to search various forums but unable to get an answer yet.
I am trying to compare exact text in protractor using `tobe` function. However, `GetText()` function in protractor is giving me text with line breaks which is not matching my expected text. Can some experts please suggest how to remove line breaks to compare this text?  I am using the below statement.

```
expect(invoice.getText()).toBe('This is my URL');`
```

Results from `GetText()` method:

> Expected 'This is
>
> my URL' to be 'This is my URL'.`

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can use `.toMatch()` matcher which would not require you to resolve a promise:

```
expect(invoice.getText()).toMatch('This is\s+my URL');
```

where `\s+` would match one or more "space" characters including a newline.

Comment: My toMatch value is in a variable. Is there any way I can still use toMatch or do I need to use method suggested by eLRull?

Comment: @NewWorld of course, you can pass it as a variable. toMatch should accept a regular string but you can also do `toMatch(new RegExp(yourVariable))`. Thanks.

Comment: This did not worked. This is what I have used in my spec file. 
 `expect(Invoice.getText()).toMatch(new RegExp(VariableName));`. Result is `- Expected 'This
is my
URL  ' to match /This is my URL/.`

Comment: @NewWorld could it be because of the trailing space in the text?

Comment: I tried with putting space in expected result also but still unable to compare.

Comment: @NewWorld have you tried to put `\s+` in place of other spaces too? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have in my variable `This is \s+my \s+URL\s+`

Comment: @NewWorld I think you have extra spaces before the `\s+`.

Comment: I checked and there are no extra spaces.

Comment: Just a detail, use : \\s+ and not just \s+.
For all the lime losed at trying to test those f*c*ing whitespace, new lines and others. Many many many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you could always `replace` the characters you don't want of a javascript string:

```
invoice.getText().then(function (text) {
    expect(text.replace(/\n/, '')).toBe('This is my URL');
})
```

Comment: Is there a way I can create a function which I can use at multiple places for thus? I tried a way but it does not seems to be working for me

Comment: @NewWorld you can also create a custom jasmine matcher to hide the logic of the replacement.

Comment: @alecxe I had two new line characters in my output. Above function replaced only one instance. I tried to use `text.replaceAll` but it seems that is an invalid function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, replaced, toMatch anything worked while I wrote correct comparison and finally I fixed it, try the following code:

```
it('Description' async function(){
    //your code
    expect(await invoice.getText()).toBe('This is\n'+ 'my URL'); 
})
```

'This is

my URL' will equal to 'This is

my URL' and eventually test will pass